# Why does fread() give seemingly random data?

Tags: c, file, fread, fseek

I have the following C code that opens a file in `rb+` mode, then writes 100 bytes of value `0`. When I read the file with an offset of anything other than 0, I get 96. Why is this?

```
FILE *fp = fopen("myfile", "rb+");
rewind(fp);
char zero = 0;
fwrite(&zero, 1, 100, fp);
char result;
fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_SET);
fread(&result, 1, 1, fp);
printf("%d\n", result);
```

I'm on Linux x64 using GCC.

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behavior, because you're writing 100 `char`s from the address of a variable (`zero`) which only has a size of 1 `char`.

Comment: So does `fread()` go to the next address after `&zero`? I wanted to fill the file with zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your clarification in the comments, your intent was to write 100 zero bytes to the file. There are at least two and possibly three ways to do this.

The first is to allocate an array of 100 zero-initialized bytes, and write that:

```
char zeroes[100] = { 0 };
fwrite(zeroes, sizeof(char) /* == 1 */, sizeof(zeroes), f);
```

This doesn't scale well if you want to write, say, 10,000 or 10,000,000 zero bytes. You could also do this:

```
char zero = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) fwrite(&zero, sizeof(char), 1, f);
```

This scales better, but performs very badly since it's always more efficient to do a single large write than many tiny writes. Instead, you can seek to a later position in the file, and then write only the last byte. [On POSIX systems, this is guaranteed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek) to fill the earlier unwritten portion of the file with zeroes:

```
char zero = 0;
fseek(f, 99, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&zero, sizeof(char) /* == 1 */, 1, f);
```

I *believe* the zero-fill guarantee is also given for Windows' MSVCRT runtime, but I can't immediately find proof of that on MSDN (this might make a good question). If someone knows whether Windows, other platforms, and/or some version(s) of the C standard itself make or do not make this guarantee, this answer could be improved.

Of course, if you *are* on a POSIX system and don't need portable code, you can use [`ftruncate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/ftruncate.html) which makes the same guarantee without even needing to do an `fwrite()`. Windows has [`SetEndOfFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setendoffile) **but** that function fills the extended portion of the file with *undefined values*, not zero bytes.

Comment: "if you are on a POSIX system and don't need portable code" is a bizarre statement because **P**OSIX by definition is portable (that's what the **P** stands for).

Comment: @DYZ Portable... only to other POSIX systems! Plenty of systems are non-POSIX (like Windows) so the "P-for-Portable" won't help you much there. And POSIX itself is a notoriously loose and diversely-interpreted standard in the sense that many systems lack certain functions and some functions have behavioral quirks on many platforms.

Comment: Yet, there is no API standard that is _more_ portable than POSIX.

Comment: @DYZ How about the C Runtime Library? Or... even the Java Class Library? Even .NET Standard? All of these run on many more platforms than those which are POSIX-compliant (any version). You may have a highly UNIX-centric perspective.

Comment: We are talking about C, don't we? So, references to .NET and JCL are not very relevant. As for the libc standard, it is a proper subset of POSIX. So, no.

Comment: It is not debatable that code relying _only_ on the C standard library functions (such as my examples) is _more portable_ than code that relies on non-C-standard POSIX functions such as `ftruncate()`. My examples will all compile on Windows (without any Cygwin libraries or such) or indeed on _any_ platform with a standard-compliant C compiler and standard library. Discussion closed!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184970/discussion-between-typeia-and-dyz).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
int i; for (i=0;i<100;++i){fwrite(&zero, 1, 1, fp);}
```

You cannot write 100 bytes from a pointer that points to a single char.